# Attempt to replace "////" with "/" is not working

Tags: string, perl, replace

I need to replace all the occurrences of “////” with “/”.

I have the following code but it's not working:

```
$res =~ s/\/\/\/\//\//g;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible in perl, but maybe try `s_////_/_g`

Comment: It's working for me, replacing 4 slashes with one. Your problem most likely lies in the other code which you are not showing.

Comment: I replaced it with and it worked `$res =~ s|////|/|g;`

Comment: Also, never, ever say ["Its not working"](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) without describing how.

Comment: Please use something like `$res =~ s|[/]{4}|/|g`. These 4 Slashes are very hard to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the things that many beginners don't realize is that you don't have to use slashes as regular expression separators. In your case, it's easier to simply switch to another character. This avoids what is called the *hills and valleys* affect:

Thus, instead of this:

```
$res =~ s/\/\/\/\//\//g;
```

You can do this:

```
$res =~ s#////#/#g;
```

Pound signs (aka sharps, number signs, or octothorps) are normally used when slashes are involved in regular expressions because pound signs don't have any special meaning in regular expression syntax and aren't normally seen in syntax. However, you can use almost anything you want. Parentheses are nice too in this particular case because they're not in your regular expression and may be easier to read:

```
$res =~ s(////)(/)g;
```

Note how you match the parentheses. That is `(` marks the beginning, and `)` marks the end. Same goes with square brackets ( `[...]` ), and curly braces ( '{...}' ). Just remember to pick something that's not already in your regular expression.

By the way, the regular expression in your example works for me. Maybe you typed it here correctly and incorrectly in your program? Does your program editor use syntax highlighting?

What is the error you're getting? You say *it doesn't work*. Do you mean it doesn't compile, or that it doesn't change what you think it should change? Have you tried writing a sample program to see if it works in a simplified situation? Do you have `use warnings` and `use strict` in your program? These can help catch places where you might have *mistyped* something.

Comment: I haven't heard it called `hills and valleys`, I like that one. I have heard `leaning toothpicks` which, while descriptive, seems unrealistic :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `\K` (keep) escape sequence and a specific quantifier `{3}` to simplify your substitution. And of course, use another delimiter for `s///` to avoid the "leaning toothpick syndrome".

```
$res =~ s#/\K/{3}##g;
```